# Python profiling an inner function

Tags: python, cprofile

I am trying to profile a part of my program. The pattern is like the following:

```
def de():
      def abc():
         print("123")
      cProfile.run('abc()')
```

When I am trying to run this program, I got an error: 
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'abc' is not defined

Is there anyway to work around this error?

Comment: `run()` executes a command, not a function.

Comment: @jordanm Is that not a command?

Answer (score 4):

Everything happening outside of the function, meaning that they are hidden from the global scope.

> use runctx().
>   Please read https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#profile.runctx

```
import cProfile

def de():
      def abc():
         print("123")
      cProfile.runctx('abc()', None, locals=locals())

de()
```

**output:**

```
"123"
5 function calls in 0.000 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: in your case you could also do

```
def de():
    def abc():
        print("123")
    cProfile.run(abc.__code__)

de()
```

(creates the same output as the `runctx` variant)